# Why does my app crash at delete?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, delete-operator

```
while(!m_RemoveNodeList.empty())
{
    list<CNode *>::const_iterator const it = m_RemoveNodeList.begin();

    CNode * const pNode = *it;
    ASSERT(pNode != NULL);

    m_NodeList.remove( pNode );

    delete pNode; // crashing here

    m_RemoveNodeList.pop_front();
}
```

The above sometimes crashes at the delete with a read violation exception. could i be  that i accidentally double delete?

both m_NodeList and m_RemoveNodeList are of type

```
 std::list<CNode *>
```

i should mention that CNode is a base class for several other classes. however none of those classes does anything in their destructors

Comment: How is `m_RemoveNodeList` declared? How is it populated?

Comment: i have edited my question accordingly

Comment: It'd be worth replacing size() with empty().  If m_RemoveNodeList is a linked list then size is O(N) operation whereas empty is O(1).

Comment: Show us `CNode`'s destructor.

Comment: Any duplicated elements in m_RemoveNodeList? No other deletes of CNodes anywhere else?

Comment: @pau, good remark. i will check that.

Comment: It might be containing corrupted pointers, corrupted memory location or the location  might have freed earlier. Please track the allocation and deallocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no apparent crash in your code and looks fine.

It could crash only if there are **duplicate** `CNode*` are stored inside the `list<CNode*>`; which will lead you to multiple `delete`. (it's mentioned by @pau.estalella in the comments).

You can try following method to catch if there are **duplicate** `CNode*`.

```
map<CNode*, int> duplicate;
while(m_RemoveNodeList.size() > 0)
{
    list<CNode *>::const_iterator const it = m_RemoveNodeList.begin();
    CNode * const pNode = *it;
    if(duplicate.find(pNode) == duplicate.end())
      duplicate[pNode] = 1;
    else
      cout<<"Caught: "<<pNode<<endl;
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pNode is just a reference to the original, not a copy.  Not sure of what remove does, but if does indeed the original, you have a double delete.